# Angular6 - How to properly validate and don't accept empty input fields

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular and trying to figure out how to properly validate input field and it should not accept white spaces. I tried experimenting it with *IF statement* like below. It seems to be working just fine but when one input field is blank I get this error message:

> *ERROR TypeError: formValue.employee.trim is not a function*

```
onSubmit() { //when  the user clicks the submit button
 const formValue = this.telephoneForm.value;
 this.submitted = true;
  if (this.telephoneForm.invalid) {
   const invalidControls = this._findInvalidControls();
    if (invalidControls.length) {
    $("[formControlName=" + invalidControls[0] + "]").focus();
   }
 }

 if (
   this.telephoneForm.invalid ||
   this.alreadyExist ||
   this.noEmployeesFound ||
   this.noDepartmentsFound ||
   this.noVendorsFound
 ) {
   return;
 }


 if (
  (formValue["department"] === null ||
  formValue["department"].trim() === "") ||
  formValue["employee"] === null ||
  formValue["employee"].trim() === "" ||
  formValue["vendor"] === null ||
  formValue["vendor"].trim() === ""
 ) {
  $("[formControlName='department']").focus();
  $("[formControlName='employee']").focus();
  $("[formControlName='vendor']").focus();

  this.noEmployeesFound = true;
  this.noDepartmentsFound = true;
  this.noVendorsFound = true;

  return false;
 }
}
```

See this for
[screenshot of the form where I use this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n6nt.png)

Comment: [Duplication]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626141/form-validation-in-angular-6

Comment: @MarcFrancisco if you are use reactive form then create custom validator

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
formValue.employee.toString().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this will help you

```
    pattern: any;
        ngOninit() {
    this.pattern = "^\S{0,50}$";
//you can use this pattern to avoid space at beginning and end "^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$"
              this.telephoneForm = this.formBuilfer.group({
                employee: [null, Validators.pattern(this.pattern), Validators.required ],
        })
        }
```

above pattern will not accept space into input field and display error message in html 
like

```
<div *ngIf="employee.errors?.pattern">
    employee is not valid.
</div>
```